# DRYing up method calls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a code with similar type of methods header. I'm calling each method by defining new **def** each time and using *If..else* conditions.

```
def main_fun(data)
    id = data[0]
    day = data[1]
    if day === 1
      fun1(id)
    elsif day === 2
      fun2(id)
    elsif day === 3
      fun3(id)
    end
end

def fun1(id)
    SomeClass::Mailer.fun_1days(id).deliver_now
end

def fun2(id)
    SomeClass::Mailer.fun_2days(id).deliver_now
end

def fun3(id)
    SomeClass::Mailer.fun_3days(id).deliver_now
end

# have to add more methods for (4,5,6...) in future.
```

Can you help me **DRYing up these methods call** so I can add new methods with least updates?

Comment: sure @SebastianPalma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the architecture of your mailer class & methods. Do you really need three different mail methods or can this get DRYed?

You can pass in the days and template name

```rb
class Mailer < ApplicationMailer
  def fun(id, day_count)
    user = User.find(id)
    template = "fun_#{day_count}days"

    mail(:to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", 
     :subject => "Fun #{days}", 
     :template_name => template)
  end
end
```

and in your main function you can do

```rb
def main_fun(data)
  id = data[0]
  day = data[1]
    
  Mailer.fun(id, day).deliver_now
end
```

Meta programming like `send` / `public_send` is a powerful tool if you develop a e.g. library but in this case it makes the code harder to understand and maintain. This change also makes the code easier to extend. In case you want to introduce a 4 days mail, you only need to add another template for it and no need to c&p another method in the mailer class.